# Entity Framework update Model without losing data while using Model first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, database-migration, ef-model-first

I have seen this question a lot around here, however all the solutions involve using EF code-first. I used model-first using a designer to layout me entities and their relationships. I would like to update my production server's scheme without losing the data.

Because I am new to this I do not know what is the best solution to achieve this goal. Could I manually write the SQL code to create the new tables in my production scheme than use database-first to import the `.edmx` into Visual Studio? Would that solution work?

Or can I generate the code-first representation of my `.edmx` and then use that migration process?

Please share some knowledge.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393577/entity-framework-6-model-first-migration