# C# Dynamically Create EntityType for Database Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I'm trying to write a generic validator for the entity framework. With this validator the application itself can check wether the database is valid to the .emdx model.

Right now I'm using built in entity framework methods to validate the model against the database.

```
_context.Database.Exists()
```

and

```
_context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false)
```

The tablenames and columns are read with a simple SQL query.

```
select name from DATABASE.sys.tables order by Name
```

and

```
select COLUMN_NAME from DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = N'TABLENAME'
```

The entity framework methods return a list of [EntityType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.entitytype(v=vs.113).aspx). And this is my question, is it possible to create These [EntityTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.entitytype(v=vs.113).aspx) dynamically? The class has a static method called `EntityType.Create`, but I do not understand the parameters for this method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This isn't validation, this is what EF Migrations is supposed to be doing. Anyway, for such a check, you should be checking to see whether the tables and fields required by the model exist, not try to build EntityTypes on the fly

Comment: I'm already using the EF methods to check if the tables and columns exist. But for a better comparision I would like to have the database tables as [EntityTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.entitytype(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: How would that help? The entity types wouldn't be accurate. At best you'd be doing an approximation of checking the database. What is the real problem? Are you missing certain details/attributes?

Comment: I want to use the [EntityTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.metadata.edm.entitytype(v=vs.113).aspx) for a type validation. 
As our Database is used by many different applications changes are made often and with this class I want to prevent exceptions for applications that access the same tables.

Comment: Again, how would that help? What type validation? The EntityType you will get will vary from the one you handcrafted in the emdx model. Unless you apply the model's mappings *in reverse*, you won't even be able to compare the two. It's far easier to generate a temporary schema from the initial model and compare it to the target database, [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393577/entity-framework-6-model-first-migration)

Comment: I suggest you move away from entities and start using stored procedures and views to store and retrieve data. I know how frustrating it is when the underlying schema constantly changes. Using stored procedures and views will resolve this problem for you.